# How to run web-cam capture jar api in browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, browser, webcam-capture

I am using following http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/ api to open the web camera and capture pictures using Java swing, everything works fine but the problem is its opening as a executable jar in a separate window using JFrame. But my requirement is to open the web camera in a browser. The code i am using to open the web camera as follows:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;


public class WebcamPanelFillAreaExample  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();

        final WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        //panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);
        panel.setFillArea(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("Capture");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Capture")){

                    System.out.println("done::");
                    // get image
                    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();

                    // save image to PNG file
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Frame");
        window.add(panel);
        panel.add(button);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

    }





}
```

**Libraries i am using are:**

```
1. webcam-capture-0.3.10.jar
2. bridj-0.6.2.jar
3. slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
```

Kindly please help me to alter the code in order to open the webcam in a browser instead of opening through a executable jar window. Thanks in advance. Any sample piece of code would be much helpful to me.

Comment: It's unecessary. HTML5 provides Javascript controls to deal with camera. See this tutorial [here](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera).

Comment: Thanks. I too saw this. But how to download the code. The demo is working fine, but i really dont know to how to integrate since i am new to java, html and javascripts

Comment: If you want to keep it 'Java' then the term you need is 'Applet'.  OTOH I'd use the JS approach suggested by @BuhakeSindi (then it has nothing to do with either Java or applets).

Comment: Thanks buhake and andrew  for ur reply. Buhake suggested tutorial works fine. But the image is clarity is not good while zoomin In using canvas. That is the reason I am going with imaging api java